# How to store a query into a variable

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, query-optimization

Let's say I have this complex query snippet

```
select id, name, count(*)
from items
join ...
where <where_1st>
group by ...
having <having_1st>
```

From the table definition of `items`

```
items
-----
id ID
name varchar2
quantity number
price number
...
```

How can I store that query to a variable such that I can use a field from that query and at the same time join that query in a `union all` format. Something like this.

**Final Query:**

```
select id, name, count(*)
from items
join ...
where <where_2nd> and id not in (<first_query>.id/s)
group by ...
having <having_2nd>

union all

<first query>;
```

Can it be done in this format?

```
DECLARE
  <variable_for_1st_query>
BEGIN
  <final_query>
END;
```

Note: The query is extensive and complex. Taking this approach to reduce computing time by half.

Comment: Not quite sure what are you trying to achieve... do you really need variable, or you just want to reduce the complexity of your second query? If you are not insisting on variable you you may use `view`, or use `with data as (<first query>)` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing query into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339801/storing-query-into-a-variable)

Comment: For future reference *do not post the same question twice*. It is confusing and just wastes peoples' time. Instead, if you're not getting the correct answer, you should edit the original question to improve it.

Comment: Going to remove the other one. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is re-use the result set of the first query as a filter to the second query while also including its rows in the final output. There are a couple of ways of doing this, but the simplest - no PL/SQL required - is subquery factoring AKA the `with` clause. The `with` statement is executed once and the result set is used wherever the subquery is referenced.

So, in your example:

```
with q1 as (
    select id, name, count(*)
    from items
    join ...
    where <where_1st>
    group by ...
    having <having_1st> 
)
select id, name, count(*)
from items
join ...
where <where_2nd> 
and id not in (select q1.id from q1)
group by ...
having <having_2nd>
union all
select * from q1;
```

Because this approach is pure SQL it is easy to read the resultset. A PL/SQL approach would require a lot more infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

A assume you want to use the results of your first query twice:

- for your selection itself
- for excluding the same ids in your second selection

If your first and second select delivers the same result for `count(*)` then you can simply use `union` instead of `union all` and remove the `and id not in (<first_query>.id/s)` clause in your second select statement.

e.g.

```
-- test data for "items"
with items(id, name, val) as
 (select 1, '101', 101 from dual
  union all
  select 1, '101', 501 from dual
  union all
  select 2, '202', 202 from dual
  union all
  select 2, '202', 302 from dual
  union all
  select 3, '301', 103 from dual
  union all
  select 5, '105', 105 from dual)

select i.id, i.name, count(*)
  from items i
 where i.id < 5 -- different select ranges
 group by i.id, i.name
having avg (val) between 200 and 505 -- different group criterias

union 

select i.id, i.name, count(*)
  from items i
 where i.id > 1 --
 group by i.id, i.name
having sum (val) <= 505; --

--> result:

1   101 2
2   202 2  -- result is in both selects
3   301 1
5   105 1
```

If your first and second select delivers *different* result for `count(*)` then you can achive it by

```
-- select all
with data as (
select 1 as select_id, id, name, count(*) as total
from items
join ...
where <where_first> 
group by ...
having <having_first>
union all
select 2 as select_id, id, name, count(*) as total
from items
join ...
where <where_2nd> 
group by ...
having <having_2nd>)
-- filter results by select_id
select d.id, d.name, d.total from data d
where d.select_id = (select min(dd.select_id) from data dd where dd.id=d.id)
```

Comment: Option 1 is not guaranteed to return the desired result: without knowing the data and the details of the WHERE clauses we have no reason to assume that the second subquery would return the same counts for IDs fingered by the first subquery.

Comment: @APC That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Agreed..Frank gave the same answer first and strange he got 0 votes...So +1 from me.

Comment: Okay, allow me to rephrase my point: if both queries return the same counts for every ID in the first set then there would be no point in having two queries.

Comment: @Raj_Te - actually my solution is semantically different from Frank's second solution, although I agree they would produce the same result. I  posted my solution because I think it is more expressive of intent and closer to the OP's code, but obviously that's a matter of taste. After that it comes down to performance (it is the OP's driver after all). So, is it more efficient to restrict the second query or just select everything and filter afterwards? That depends on the execution plans and all the other stuff only the OP knows.

Comment: @APC I've added an example for the first option. As you already explained: it's impossible to give a better answer without knowing the `where clauses` and `having clauses`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 

v_query_1       VARCHAR2(100);
v_query_2       VARCHAR2(200);
v_query_3       VARCHAR2(300);
v_query_main    VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN

v_query_1    := 'First query';
v_query_2    := 'Second query';
v_query_3    := 'Third query';
v_query_main := v_query_1||'UNION ALL'||v_query_2||'UNION ALL'||v_query_3;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_main;

END;
/
```